# How to remove insertion of double quotes on marked word in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9

This new function in Xcode 9 *seems* to be alright, but I can't get used to it, and in most cases it turns out to require me to do more work than the old native function.

How can I prevent Xcode from quoting a marked word, rather than replacing the marked word with a single quote?

[image: Quotes]

In this case, when marking the word `Text` and hitting ***"***, I want the result to be `Some"`, not `Some"Text"`. When marking the entire `SomeText`-word and hitting ***"***, I expect the result to be a single `"`, not a quoted `"SomeWord"`.

As someone who uses more than just Xcode to write text in my life, I get annoyed when each of the text-editors wants to have their own custom features, and I end up confusing the features with different editors..

Comment: This annoys me a ton. I replace words with quotes all the time and now I have to add the backspace key to this operation.

Answer (score 1):

I got in this issue too and also think that this is really annoying.
After some ivestigation, i've found out that there is a key to insert quote without Extra Action:
[image]

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: I also have this, but it doesn't actually work. Shift+2 is " for me, and ctrl+shift+2 does exactly the same as shift+2. This might be due to my keyboard having norwegian layout though.. So still no joy for me.. Even if I change this Key to simply `"`, nothing changes and it still marks the entire word.

Comment: This is the same command. Unfortunately it became the default case for all quotes.