# XCode9 - how to restore original text overwrite behavior when used on selected text?

Tags: xcode, syntax, autocomplete, xcode9

I see that XCode 9 has an unplesant new bug/feature, where if I have some swift string selected, typing " adds an extra " at the end of the string:

```
"Existing String" //selected by double clicking on quotes
""Existing String"" //adding another quote does not overwrite the string, but wraps it in more quotes, resulting in utter nonsense
```

I get two empty strings with an unknown reference in between. I expected to get a new empty string.

The new behavior is similar with [ ] in Objective-C code. I want to overwrite the method, instead I get an extra pair of brackets.

**How do I prevent XCode from inserting quotes or brackets around selected text if it already has quotes or brackets?**

PS. I'm getting other text editing bugs as well, most notably the { not being balanced by a closing } when creating new Obj-C methods.

Comment: I hate Xcode 9 because of this , also in `print` method, I get used to write 2 double quotes and then a back arrow to write in the middle and now with Xcode 9 this becomes a nightmare as it automatically adds another double quote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove insertion of double quotes on marked word in Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462872/how-to-remove-insertion-of-double-quotes-on-marked-word-in-xcode-9)